# Rails mailer working on controller but not on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have set a mailer:

```
def created_poll_email(poll)
    @poll = poll
    mail(subject: 'A new poll was created! ' + @poll.question)
  end
```

Firstly I was calling it on polls controller:

```
  def create
   @poll = Poll.new(poll_params.merge(user: current_user))
   if @poll.save
   PollMailer.created_poll_email(@poll).deliver_now
```

And it was working fine.

Now I want to move it to a callback on model:

```
after_save :send_email

def send_email
  PollMailer.created_poll_email(@poll).deliver_now
end
```

But now i get error undefined method `question' for nil:NilClass. I tried to set also other callbacks as after_create or after_commit but same result.
Why is this happening and how can I fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `@poll`, which isn't set inside your model, with `self`:

```
def send_email
  PollMailer.created_poll_email(self).deliver_now
end
```